# custom docker container for Apache NiFi

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I have created a custom docker container to run Apache NiFi and later some other bits on top of NiFi.
The container is running Ubuntu 18
The nifi.properties file is pretty vanilla.
Here is my docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM openjdk:8-jre

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN mkdir /opt/MicroFocus
RUN apt-get install dos2unix 

WORKDIR /opt/nifi/
RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/1.11.4/nifi-1.11.4-bin.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf nifi-1.11.4-bin.tar.gz
ADD nifi.properties /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/conf
RUN chmod 777 /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/conf/nifi.properties
RUN dos2unix /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/conf/nifi.properties

ADD start.sh /opt/nifi
RUN chmod 777 start.sh
RUN dos2unix start.sh
ADD nifi-env.sh /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/bin
RUN chmod 777 /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/bin/nifi-env.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/bin/nifi.sh","start"]
```

This is part of a larger docker compose setup. So when I run

```
docker compose build nifi
```

It builds without any errors. Then we I run

```
docker compose up nifi
```

I get the following output after which the container terminates.

```
[+] Running 1/1
 - Container nifi_tnsw  Recreated                                                                                                           0.3s
Attaching to nifi_tnsw
nifi_tnsw  |
nifi_tnsw  | Java home: /usr/local/openjdk-8
nifi_tnsw  | NiFi home: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4
nifi_tnsw  |
nifi_tnsw  | Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/conf/bootstrap.conf
nifi_tnsw  |
nifi_tnsw  |
nifi_tnsw exited with code 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to enable verbose log in apache nifi?

Comment: `service` by and large just doesn't work in Docker.  You need to find some way to run the server as a foreground process.  I'd recommend making that be the image's `CMD`, not its `ENTRYPOINT`, so it's easier to do things like get a debug shell to understand what's wrong.

Comment: I have changed to use ENTRYPOINT and firing off a shell script. But its still the same result. See my modified dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every container, there should be a foreground process there to prevent container exit. `/opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4/bin/nifi.sh start` will start the process in background, then exit, which finally make the container exit as no foreground process running.

For you, you may directly use the [apache/nifi](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi) image on dockerhub:

```
docker run -d --name nifi -p 8080:8080 apache/nifi:latest
```

Of course, if you insist to write your own dockerfile, then you could reference above one to prevent container exit:

1. Refers to their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile#L101), they use a script as entrypoint:

   ```
   ENTRYPOINT ["../scripts/start.sh"]
   ```
2. Refers to their [start.sh](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub/sh/start.sh#L108), this will will use `wait` command to wait until the main process exit, then you will always have a foreground process in container which will prevents the container exit:

```
NIFI_HOME=/opt/nifi/nifi-1.11.4
"${NIFI_HOME}/bin/nifi.sh" run &
nifi_pid="$!"
tail -F --pid=${nifi_pid} "${NIFI_HOME}/logs/nifi-app.log" &

trap 'echo Received trapped signal, beginning shutdown...;./bin/nifi.sh stop;exit 0;' TERM HUP INT;
trap ":" EXIT

echo NiFi running with PID ${nifi_pid}.
wait ${nifi_pid}
```